# Why I have 300 process apache sleeping if I have MaxClients = 200?

Tags: apache-2.2

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers            150
    MinSpareServers         5
    MaxSpareServers         20
    ServerLimit             200
    MaxClients              200
    MaxRequestsPerChild     0
</IfModule>
```

`top` after apache stop responding:

[image]

After few hours of running my server stops responding due to too many apache processses in sleeping... And only thing I can do is to restart apache

What can I do? I am on debian 6 with LAMP
KeepAlive is off for the moment.

Comment: The 317 processes listed in `top` include all processes, not just Apache processes.

Comment: What are your keepalive settings, your sleeping processes could be waiting for connections if they are set very high...

Comment: Off...............

Comment: @Shane: i doubt I have 100 other process

Comment: Sure you do, or at least close to it.  Stop Apache and see for yourself.  Anyway, if your problem is that Apache is becoming unresponsive, you should probably be giving some details about that; what kind of response do page requests get?  Anything in Apache's error logs?

Comment: Error logs is clean (only hundreds of 404s pages). For your first question I honestly don't get what you mean

Comment: yes123: There is no evidence above showing that you have 300 apache processes. Please do a count of the Apache httpd processes with a command like `ps aux |grep --count httpd`.

Comment: @Stefan: `top` atm shows 161 total, your command echoes `37`. So when there are 300 process in total, apache are about 180. Anyway now I have maxclient at 150. Let's see if apache stops again

Comment: This means that you currently have 37 httpd proceesses, and about 161 processes total (not unusual for a Linux system). If you run that `grep` command periodically you might see the number of httpd processes grow over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should figure out how much RAM each Apache process uses on average. Run `ps -ylC apache2 --sort:rss` to get a rough estimate -- total up the RAM and divide by the number of processes. You might want to exclude any values that are wildly different.

Then take a look at the total RAM usage, and subtract the Apache usage.

MaxClients should be set to roughly: ((total RAM) - (RAM used by processes other than Apache) - (some cushion)) / (average RAM used by Apache processes)

EDIT: Also you may want to look at the output of [mod_status](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Monitoring_Apache_with_mod_status) to see if there are a lot of processes in the KeepAlive state ("K"). If so you need to reduce your KeepAliveTimeout setting.

Comment: the RSS entries are about 14000. I have 4GB ram

Comment: KeepAlive is off

Comment: Any reason why KeepAlive is off? Have you tried turning it on?

Comment: to simplify the debug, it has been always on, with a timeout of 2-3sec. So keepalive isn't the problem. Which values of maxclients and serverlimit do you suggest me?

Comment: How many apache2 processes are there?

Comment: How can i check ? Ah with your command wait a moment

Comment: I coutned 31 apache2 process. But I have started apache few minutes ago. `top` shows 142 total task (i have reduced maxclients to 150 now)

Comment: Sorry I missed that you said _each_ process is about ~14 MB. MySQL is probably your other main memory hog. So if you figure about 1 GB (guessing) for MySQL and 1 GB for other processes, Apache could safely consume 2 GB RAM. So 150 may be a little high. I'd try 125.

Comment: thank you. With 150 apache2 is up and running for ~24h without problems now. I will wait more. If it hangs out again i will take that to 125

Comment: apache2 now seems to be responsive without any problems. Maybe the problem was really that :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html). Read that page for details and security considerations.
2. View the server status at http://example.org/server-status?refresh=N (Refresh every N seconds) . You will see each httpd child, the page it is serving, the IP of the client which requested the page, etc.

Things to look for:

- Usually when Apache has too many children, it's because one page or a
  set of related pages are hanging due to code issues. Look for httpd
  children which are all serving the same page. That page may be buggy.
- If one client is hammering your server by requesting multiple pages in quick
  succession, you can see it on this page.
- Sometimes you can also detect a DDOS on this page. Look for multiple IPs all requesting the same buggy page, or requesting multiple slow pages. DDOSes are hard to detect, due to their nature.

Answer (score 1):

First doublecheck if you actually *do* have 300 apache processes with something like `pgrep -c apache2`.

It is possible you changed the config but haven't restarted yet (this can easily stretch into many weeks).

If your server stops responding, is it only the apache server, or the entire system? Try to monitor your memory usage (the memory-free metric is far easier to measure than the total usage by all processes).